# How to check if a Point is inside a Polygon

Tags: java, location, entity, coordinates

I've got a `Polygon`:

[image]

I want to check if the Location of an Entity is inside this `Polygon`.
As example x:5 and y:5, How can I make a check to see if this Coordinate is inside this Polygon (Java)?

Comment: Read: [Point in Polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

Comment: Or invoke `java.awt.Polygon#contains()`. Is this an analytic geometry problem or a rendering problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you create the polygon using the `Polygon` class that is included with java use the `contains()` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html

Take a look at the method summary:

`contains(int x, int y)` -  Determines whether the specified coordinates are inside this `Polygon`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks like it will do the trick.
I was looking at http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/
But your suggestion is way to go.